# Native development with xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am just a beginner to Xamarin, Can any body explain me in more simple way here is the statements :-

`Access to native APIs
Allows you to create native apps with device-specific experiences.`

Is it mean that whatever an `Android` developer can do in `Java` e.g everything about device api etc. I can do the same using `Xamarin` in `C#` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Access to native API's:
Xamarin.Android allows access to the same native API's as a Java-developed app.

Allows you to create native apps with device-specific experiences:
Xamarin.Android allows you to create apps that offer the same device-specific experience (look & feel, etc) as native apps.

Comment: so it mean it is just same as developing android app using java - no restriction to anything right ?

Comment: It means that anything you can do in an Android app using Java you can also do in a Xamarin.Android app using C#.

Answer (score 1):

The native APIS are bridged from java based android over to xamarin.android in C#, and therefore available to you just in a c# xamarin platform. Similarly, ios/objective-c native APIs are bridged to xamarin.ios c# platform as well. 
And now windows phone is included.

A good description on how it works is here on the xamarin website:
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/

That section also discusses some limitations set by a gap in languages & their frameworks in the bridging process. However, that doesn't seem to be a problem for most applications.

You can create apps with device specific experience meaning that you're using the native ui controls. For instance, iOS uses a spinner where an android equivalent uses drop down boxes as opposed to a web based application that doesn't invoke those types of controls. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Access to native API's:** 
   I recommend you to refer to the following link
   [platform's native text-to-speech API](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/text-to-speech/)
     this **example** clearly explains how to call into each ***platform's native text- to-speech API*** using Dependency service technique.
2. Allows you to create native apps with device-specific experiences.:

[image: Xamarin achieves native UI experiences as shown in below.]